# How to get rid of validation warnings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, response

The complete warning is Validation (): Element 'html' occurs too few times

This is for a JSON view, which you might guess returns a JSON result and hence no html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC has the ability to return JSON data as a proper json response.  It seems you're using HTTP response which expects HTML to exist in it.

Here is an example of [using JSON.NET to build a JSON ActionResult](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dev102.com/2008/08/19/jquery-and-the-aspnet-mvc-framework/ Here is another tutorial as well.